# How can I run a program on a computer to receive USART data in AVR32 UC3A sent from an oscilloscope

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to run and test a program for receiving USART data from a MAX232 which is coming from an oscilloscope (RS232.)

I am using an AVR32 UC3A microcontroller and the code is for receiving USART data using an interrupt. I compiled it and no errors so far in Microchip Studio. As I am trying to use this finally to receive data from an oscilloscope connected to a MAX232 and then to the EVK1104, I understand the code should be uploaded to the microcontroller (pre-programmed.)

Can I just run the program for now by connecting a laptop to the board and receiving data in the microcontroller to test it without uploading code to the board?

Comment: use a serial terminal program, such as Putty ... https://putty.org/

Comment: Thank you, I used putty and chose serial port, but my laptop is not recognizing EVK1104 board. I look in device manager to find any info under port, but I do not see any port information also in device manager to find which COMx port is being used. I am connecting board (serial_ to my laptop(USB) and then open putty. Is this the right path? Another question, without board, when I try to run program after compiling and no error, it fails. Should program be able to run successfully with no board connected and just not taking any action? I am using microchip studio by the way as IDE.

Comment: why is all of this information in a comment? ... information and questions belong in the question at the top of this webpage